# How can I increase security on this project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

Preface: I'm new to developing for secure commercial applications, and I understand that I may be too sensitive.

I'm working with a supervisor as a freelancer on a project that uses very truncated version of Forms Authentication and an SHA1 hash sans salt. The project uses no other security, and I've been explicitly ordered not to use any built in security that would ordinarily come with an MVC application, along with a few of the rendering/scripting libraries and the built in methods for role authentication or data annotation.

To the best of my knowledge, the application will not be interacting with legacy code, and the choice to use these methods does not lie in backwards compatibility with any already existing code bases.

The project uses a home brew method for encryption, roles, and security that uses a version of SHA1 and overrides or does not make use of many of the Forms Authentication methods.

Data stored by the application will include financial and personal records for a variety of entities and individuals ranging from small businesses to government entities.

I have mentioned several times that I am uncomfortable with the fact that the application does not use most MVC security tools, urged my boss to let me use more security, and have documented my issues with the project.

I have also spent hours reading on Asp.Net Identity and other tools in preparation for customizing them according to the project requirements while maintaining things I consider necessary, but was refused permission to do so.

Despite my worries, I want to finish the project if at all possible, preferably in a way that does not expose the users too badly or myself to legal ramifications for the kind of data that could be exposed here.

Given the following conditions, I would like to know if there are any specific ways to increase the security of this project:

1. Can't use OWIN/OAuth or Asp.Net Identity.
2. Initial authentication must be performed against the same table where sensitive user and financial information is stored in plain text. All subsequent authentication and roles management is performed against the home brew code, which stores session variables.
3. No salt may be used with passwords.
4. Password length is the only requirement for creating passwords, and the required length is very short.
5. Can't track or limit how many times a user can try to access or log into the system.
6. Can't use two-factor authentication.
7. Can't set the authentication ticket or security cookie to expire promptly.
8. Can't use data annotations for roles, authorization, and to some degree for validation on incoming data (some things have been nixed, others not).
9. Can't use anyone else's tools for security.
10. Can't create or limit roles using any of the built in classes/must use home brew method for limiting roles only.
11. Can't use the User.Identity object or methods.

In general, because of the nature of the data being stored, I am worried that the home brew security, coupled with the absence of current security tools, has created a situation in which it is extraordinarily difficult for sensitive information not to be exposed.

My communication with my supervisor is very poor. I'm hoping that any responses will give me more/better ways to communicate the vulnerabilities I'm seeing. No doubt I'm being annoying to my boss at this point, likely a contributing factor in our communication break down, but I'm very, very worried about all this.

And again, I am prepared to hear I'm being over-sensitive or that I am in the wrong. I am keenly aware that as a new developer, I have yet to develop a full understanding of the field. The vast majority of my experience has been academic, and I know that the classroom is not necessarily a good model for the actual practice of software development.

I'm also prepared to hear I should just finish the project and leave my boss alone.

But to the best of my knowledge, whatever that can be said to be, what I'm creating will be trivially easy to break, and I feel obliged to try and do something to make it a little harder for all the reasons above.

Comment: LMFAO... here is a list of 11 things you must do... most of which will make your app difficult to secure... now make it secure... LMFAO ... who the frik told them it was a good idea to impose those restrictions? They need a security consultant that knows what they are doing.

Comment: That was my conclusion, but because I'm so new to this, I wasn't sure if I was seeing it correctly and/or wasn't applying the classroom to the situation--assuming a more ideal situation than actually exists out here in the real world. Thank you.

Comment: Here's one tip: The signed sesssion ID is stored in the cookie... someone gets the cookie... they can impersonate you easily.

Comment: One more tip before I do some work... the reason why salting passwords is necessary... sha1 not reversible? lol http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure-for-password-storage

Comment: One more lol.. Point 5. Translate to, "allow brute force attacks"... do you think this might be a test? To see if you realise it's a daft set of requirements?

Comment: I would hope so, but every version I've created that used the tools has been sent back telling me to take them off, and my attempts to discuss the vulnerabilities have been dismissed summarily. It is my opinion (take me with a salt shaker, of course) that the requests are being made sincerely.

Comment: Like you've said... cover your own ass... constant rebuttles are a nuisance... keep copies of your conversations... although that itself could contravene security I guess... you can only do what they are asking for eh.

Comment: It looks like the only to improve security for this project, is to blow the whistle on them, by either going public or reporting them to the data protection authorities of your country. If you cannot or don't want to do that: refuse to build a project like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've written here this sounds like the kind of project you would not want to be involved in. The constraints you listed sound like they are building a web app from the 90s. It sounds like they have covered all the bases as far as things you don't want to to if you plan to make you application secure go.

The only thing I can think of to say is that you should make sure they use https. Also, Captchas haven't been listed here explicitly, but they probably fall under 3rd party tools.
You should probably revise the homebrew codebase to see if you can strengthen it?

And you should probably have a long hard think about whether this job is worth the trouble or not...

Comment: I can ensure that the project uses https. And I am having that think right now. Thank you.

Comment: Hey... as long as you cover yourself legally... as long as it puts food on the table eh... They have given you massive restrictions... what are the requirement specs?

Comment: @PaulZahra That is true. I guess it depends what your options are. if there is nothing else to work on, then you probably have to stick with, even if it probably will not be a nice few months to get through. It might not look good on your portfolio either. But, the way it has been described, with all those constraints and poor communications with the supervisor. It sounds like a project you'd not want to get involved with if you have any other option.